# Android Facebook sharing with deep links

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, applinks

I am currently sharing a link in my Android app by creating a chooser with an `ACTION_SEND`-Intent. I now want to add deep linking to the posts which already works with links from our iOS app into the Android app but not from links shared with the Android app. I think the reason is that by using an Intent, the app that actually posts the share is the Facebook app and not my own app.
So I probably have to use FacebookDialog to get this working, right?
If this is so, can I somehow still get the chooser? I still want the user to be able to select the service to share with.

I also know about App Links, does anyone know if using this would also solve the issue? Can links via App Links be referenced to the right app although they were shared with the Standard Facebook app?
The Facebook App Links documentation does not say much about sharing content from the app, only how to link from a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no app attribution available from a standard ACTION_SEND intent, Facebook will not know how to deep link into your app.

Using FacebookDialogs will give you app attribution, but will not address the chooser issue.

Using App Links is your best bet. It will tell Facebook how to deep link into your app (Facebook will scrape any link that is shared, so it will know about your App Links), and is a completely server side change, so you don't need to change any of your client code at all (assuming your client code already supports deep linking).

Comment: Thx for the answer! So for the App Links you just have to add the metadata to your website and Facebook will recognize any link that points to such a site as an App Link? That would be the way to go then.

Comment: From my first tests that seems to be not right. When I share a link from within the app via the ACTION_SEND intent, the linking works now with the App Links meta tags but if I just post a link in my newsfeed it is not recognized as a link into the app. Also older posts from the iOS app are also not recognized. So I guess the link has to be posted from an App (iOS or Android) and the linked site has to have the meta tags present at the moment of the post, not when clicking on the link. But it's in so far right that it solves the intent problem.

Comment: Posting directly from newsfeed should work as well. Feel free to PM me your url, and I can test for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I think the link we tested was somehow cached by Facebook, so it didn't work with that one. All others are deep linking like expected.